# Programmatically create user reference field

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users, entities

I want to add a user reference field in taxonomy term. I create field and it's instance:

```
$field = ['field_name' => 'mymodule_employee',
        'label' => t('Employee'),
        'type' => 'entityreference',
        'cardinality' => 1,
        'settings' => [
            'target_type' => 'user',
            'handler' => 'base',
            'handler_settings' => [
                'target_bundles' => ['user']
            ],
        ],
];
field_create_field($field);

$instance = ['mymodule_employee' => [
            'entity_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
            'bundle' => 'my_vocabulary',
            'field_name' => 'mymodule_employee',
            'label' => t('Employee'),
            'widget' => array(
                'type' => 'options_select',
                'active' => 1,
            ),
            'settings' => array(
                'target_type' => 'user',
                'handler_settings' => array('target_bundles' => null),
                'handler' => 'base',
            ),
            'display' => array(
                'default' => array('label' => 'inline', 'type' => 'entityreference_label'),
            ),
            'required' => 0,
            'default_value' => null,
        ],
];
field_create_instance($instance);
```

Everything goes ok. But when I'm creating the term and try to choose a user there is an empty list. When I go to the field settings in admin form and just save it, everything begins to work.

What do I forget creating field and instance?

Comment: Would just using [Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) be an option?

Comment: It works with this module if User Reference is set in admin form. It does not work if is is set programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Check if [Entity Reference Autocomp](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autocomplete)lete  module helps you. The module page says

> This module defines a new form element type, called "entityreference",
>   that allows developers to add autocomplete fields to forms, so that
>   users can reference any entity in the same way they would do through
>   an Entity Reference field.

Answer (score 1):

To add a reference to the user, use the References module, and then enable the User Reference module defined by it.

Then you will need to define the field in your hook_enable or hook_install function. Do something like the following:

```
$field = array(
  'field_name' => 'vendor_user_reference',
  'type' => 'user_reference',
  'cardinality' => 1,
  'entity_types' => array('commerce_product'),
  'translatable' => FALSE,
  'settings' => array(
            'referenceable_status' => array(
               0 => 0,
               1 => '1',
             ),  
    )       
);
field_create_field($field);
```

You MUST define a value for referenceable_status.  If you don't, the user list will not populate in the interface.  You can also at this time define the referenceable_roles array too.  It would look something like this:
    'referenceable_roles' => array(
      2 => 0,
      3 => 0,
      4 => '4',
      5 => 0,
      6 => 0,
    ),

where you set the role you want to the rid from the role table.

You will then need to create an instance of the field on your entity.  I did the following for a Drupal Commerce Product. (for Commerce Kickstart 2.0, this goes in the hook_commerce_product_type_insert($product_type, $skip_reset) for a product type entity.)

```
$new_instance = array(
  'field_name' => 'vendor_user_reference',
  'entity_type' => 'commerce_product',
  'bundle' => $product_type['type'],
  'label' => t('Vendor User Reference'),
  'required' => TRUE,
  'widget' => array(
                'active' => 1,
                'module' => 'options',
                'settings' => array(
                        'apply_chosen' => '',
                ),
                'type' => 'options_select',
                'weight' => '40',
        ),
   'display' => array(),
);
field_create_instance($new_instance);
```

Now, if you want to set the value of the select list that is created for the users (say the logged in user), You will need to modify your hook_form_alter function to add the following:

```
$entity_form['vendor_user_reference']['und']['#default_value'] = (string)$user->uid;
```

I am not quite sure why I need the ['und'] for my form, but it wouldn't work without it.